# Python module does not work as expected, if used as custom keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

If I call this pathon function from console, the dates are calculated as expected:

```
def get_nearest_date(day, month):
    """Gets nearest date in the future for provided day and month."""
    today = date.today()
    res = ""
    if (today.month < month):
        res = str(day) + "." + str(month) + "." + str(today.year)
    elif ((today.month == month) & (today.day < day)):
        res = str(day) + "." + str(month) + "." + str(today.year)
    else: 
        res = str(day) + "." + str(month) + "." + str((today.year + 1))
    return res
```

for example:

```
print   get_nearest_date(1, 1)
print   get_nearest_date(1, 12)
```

returns

```
1.1.2016
1.12.2015
```

But if I use this function as custom keyword in a Robot Framework testcase like this

```
Bla    
    ${d} =    Get Nearest Date    1   1
    Log To Console  ${d}
    ${d} =    Get Nearest Date    1   12
    Log To Console  ${d}
```

it prints

```
Bla                                                                   
1.1.2015
1.12.2015
```

which is wrong (first date should be **2016**). Why is this?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using `'{}.{}.{}'.format(...)` over all that string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to realise that in RF the parameters passed to my custom keyword

```
${d} =    Get Nearest Date    1   1
```

are actually strings. Passing number variables solves this issue:

```
${d} =    Get Nearest Date     ${1}    ${1}
```